# Why is this for loop on columns [0-15] not working?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataset:

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {'sequence': 1, 'timingDate': '2022-01-07', 'c... | {'sequence': 2, 'category.coding': [{'code' | {'sequence': 3, 'category.coding': [{'code': |

I am able to do this individually; however, this take a long time. A loop would be more efficient. There is actually 0-15 columns that need to be applied

Essentially this what the loop should do.

```
one_st = sI[0].apply(pd.Series)
two_st = sI[1].apply(pd.Series)
three_st = sI[2].apply(pd.Series)
# and so on through column 15
```

This is my code.

```
sI = pd.json_normalize(df30['supportingInfo'])
for i in range(len(sI)):
    sI[i].apply(pd.Series)
```

My error is this:

KeyError: 13

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could apply your function on each column of a dataframe in a single statement:

```
df = df.apply(pd.Series)  # Also... df.apply(lambda column: pd.Series(column))
```

Now, the problem with `KeyError: 13` means that there's not column with name `13` on your dataframe. You could check the name of your columns by printing the column names:

```
print(df.columns)  # If you have many columns... print(list(df.columns))
```

Also, you could just apply your function on the first 15 columns, whatever their name is:

```
df[df.columns[:15]] = df[df.columns[:15]].apply(pd.Series)
```